# Configuring RADIUS or LDAP on Supermicro (ATEN) IPMI

Tags: authentication, ldap, radius, ipmi, supermicro

I'm trying to get our new server, a X8DTN+-F's IMPI configured to talk to our authentication servers. The two choices are LDAP and RADIUS.

I'm debugging this by looking at packet captures, as it seems the IPMI stuff doesn't log anything.

I first tried LDAP, but the IMPI stuff insisted on binding as a user other than the one logging in (wtf). Once I set it up its own user, it managed to find the user (though not by searching for the attribute I wanted, and there seemed no way to change it), but even upon getting a response... didn't allow the login. Maybe it expected a password attribute in the response, which of course it didn't get. It should just bind as the user who is logging in (and should use LDAP over SSL, but that's another story).

So I tried RADIUS. Now, it sends the expected Access-Request packet (with expected username, an encrypted password, a NAS IP Address of 127.0.0.1 [wtf], and a port of 1). It then gets back an access-accept packet, with a service-type of Administrative-User… and then it rejects the login.

(Note: by rejects the login, I mean redisplays the login page. Its not like this thing believes in error messages. Or logs.)

So, is there some magic attribute I need to get the RADIUS server to reply with? Has anyone gotten RADIUS to work with Supermicro's IPMI

Comment: Which IPMI Firmware version are you using? I've got v 1.32 on an X8DTH-6F, and it only has LDAP and AD options, no RADIUS.

Comment: @aniel Lawson: 2.01 now. Turns out there are definitely some weird attributes that need to be set, they sent me a doc with some examples but no explanation. Still following up to find out what they mean...

Comment: For me the IPMI LDAP Authentification with Supermicro (Aten) did work with greater than Version 3.10 but not with less than Version 2.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the magic numbers, which I have no idea of the meaning, that I got (a while ago) from Supermicro (via our vendor, Silicon Mechanics):

```
#vi /etc/raddb/users

Example:
    myuser          Auth-Type   :=Local, User-Password == “123456”
                    Vendor-Specific = “H=4, I=4”

    testuser        Auth-Type   :=Local, User-Password == “654321”
                    Vendor-Specific = “H=3, I=3”
```

So, obviously H= and I= mean something, and at least 3 and 4 are valid values (and I don't believe the syntax is even allowed by the RFCs, but whatever). I replied asking what those mean, and haven't heard back. I just sent a followup...

### edit

Got a reply:
>

> Those setting match the user account type in IPMI Web GUI.
>
> CallBack (H=1, I=1) = No Access
>   Basically, this type of account will be rejected by IPMI.  It can be used to temporarily disable an account.
>
> User (H=2, I=2) = User
>   This type of the account is only allowed to check the system status.
>
> Operator (H=3, I=3) = Operator
>   This type of the account is allowed to do the remote control & check the system statsus, but can't change the configuration.
>
> Administrator (H=4, I=4) = Administrator
>   The type of accout is allowed to do everything.
>
> There is no other privilege.

### edit 2

Reply to the two different field meanings.

> This is the info SuperMicro got from ATEN:
>
> "H" means if for the user privilege.  IPMI spec 2.0 defines the following channel privilege levels.  We don't use the OEM Proprietary level for special privilege.
>
> Channel Privilege Level Limit:
>         0h = reserved
>         1h = CALLBACK level
>         2h = USER level
>         3h = OPERATOR level
>         4h = ADMINISTRATOR level
>         5h = OEM Proprietary level
>
> "I" is for debug purpose and it is reserved option. Please ignore it.
>
> Below is the definition of the Channel Privilege Levels from IPMI spec 2.0:
>
> Callback
>   This may be considered the lowest privilege level. Only commands necessary to support initiating a Callback are allowed.
>
> User
>   Only 'benign' commands are allowed. These are primarily commands that read data structures and retrieve status. Commands that can be used to alter BMC configuration, write data to the BMC or other management controllers, or perform system actions such as resets, power on/off, and watchdog activation are disallowed.
>
> Operator
>   All BMC commands are allowed, except for configuration commands that can change the behavior of the out-of band interfaces. For example, Operator privilege does not allow the capability to disable individual channels, or change user access privileges.
>
> Administrator
>   All BMC commands are allowed, including configuration commands. An Adminstrator can even execute
>   configuration commands that would disable the channel that the Administrator is communicating over.

Comment: Could you please post the settings supplied by Supermicro here?

I have a similar issue and cannot get hold of anyone knowledgeable from Supermicro.

]-[

Comment: @Hunta: I now have an answer from SuperMicro. Edited in.

Comment: @Hunta: updated. Not sure if you're watching this. I think I've now got a full answer.